# ¿Cómo puedo importar una libreria no nativa de Cordova a un proyecto Ionic?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic, typescript

Hay una librería de **Cordova** que me gustaría usar en un proyecto de **Ionic** pero no se muy bien como hacerlo. ¿alguien podría echarme una mano?

Esta es la librería en cuestión

https://github.com/Red-Folder/bgs-core

Comment: Instala lo con `npm` => https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-bgs-core

Comment: Yo añadía directamente el servicio con cordova plugin add... ¿Qué diferencia hay? Y una vez que lo has instalado con Npm hace falta hacer algún import o como puedes empezar a usar el plugin? Porque en la documentacion no veo nada que me pueda servir. Gracias